# Can Google Analytics and Plus display my browsing history?

Tags: google-analytics

If I'm logged into my google account and I am surfing the net can anyone see my browsing history? and here I refer to people or friends from Google Plus which visted my G+ account or websites using Google Analytics. 
Google says that the browsing history is private and only the owner of the account can see it, but I was wondering if Google Analytics or Google plus can show to other users my browsing history.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because about how users are tracked online and is not remotely programing related.

Answer (score 1):

Basically no one else your browser's history. Unless you have left your computer open for others to access your browser with your login credentials.

Comment: No one has access to my pc, but I was curios if someone's website using Google Analytics can see my browsing history, except the time spent on his page which is of course visible to him. I know that Google Analytics sends some cookies regarding the user and was curious if my browsing history is sent also to them if i'm logged into my Google Account.